# How Make Multiple Phone Call in Twilio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

i don't know if this question is already asked before because i didn't see any.

I would like to make multiple phone call to my client at fixed time every day. Every day i like to wake up my client at 9.00AM . I have successful to call one number using click-to-call example by using rails.

But i don't an have idea how can i send request to twilio to make multiple call at once without queueing all my call. How can i do so ? I don't want my call to be in queue. Please guide me.

Comment: Again, downvote without explaination.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can make multiple calls at the same time with Twilio, but there will be an amount of queueing as each account can make [one outgoing call per second](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183648-Sending-and-Receiving-Limitations-on-Calls-and-SMS-Messages).

To make the calls at 9am every morning, you could write a Ruby script that runs through a list of numbers that you want to call (you could hardcode this, get numbers from your database or store them any way you want) and [initiates a call using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls) with them.

To schedule the script to run, you could use a [cron job](https://www.howtogeek.com/101288/how-to-schedule-tasks-on-linux-an-introduction-to-crontab-files/) to run the script regularly. If you want to use cron in a Ruby way, then check out the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever). Alternatively, if you are using a platform as a service, like Heroku, they tend to have job schedulers too.